# initialising and incrementing nested dict python

Tags: dictionary

I am sorry if this has been asked elsewhere, but have been trying and googling all day to solve this to no avail.

I wish to initialise an empty dict as such:

`empty_dict = {}`

Then, I take rows from a csv file, saved into a variable, lets say `saved_word_list`. In this `saved_word_list` are the rows from the csv file which contain sentences. Each of these sentences on the rows are identified as either `A` or `B`. What I would like to do is to populate the `empty_dict` with each unique word in the sentence so that each word is only counted once per line and added to the correct nested portion of the dict.

An example:

`row_1 = {"this is a fine day to do a lot of coding"}`

This row would be labelled `A`, so our list would change to:

`empty_dict = {'this':{'A':1,'B':0}, 'is':{'A':1, 'B':0}, 'a':{'A':1, 'B':0}.....}`

So, below is as much as I have, but I would like to get to understanding how to reach the goal of the line above. Any ideas how I can get to this point?

```
for (sentence, label) in zip(saved_word_list, labels):
    keys = set(labels)
    values = set(sentence.split())
    for key in keys:
      for value in values:
        if value not in empty_Dict:
          empty_Dict[value][key] = value
        else:
          empty_Dict[value][key] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do exactly what you want.

```
def template_inner_dict():
    """
    Creates an template dictionary with the row labels as keys
    and 0 as values
    """
    return {i: 0 for i in labels}


empty_dict = {}
for (sentence, label) in zip(saved_word_list, labels):
    tokens = set(sentence.split())
    for token in tokens:
        # insert a template dict for the value not present in the dict
        if token not in empty_dict:
            empty_dict[token] = template_inner_dict()
        # increment the label count associated with token by 1
        empty_dict[token][label] += 1
```

Comment: This is great, however, I am getting key errors, and am not sure how to get around these.

```{'RT', '#MakeAmericaGreatAgain', '@EricTrump:', ''}```

Above is the value of tokens when I print to command line. The key error in this case I get is:

```KeyError: 'RT'```

I feel like I have misunderstood something about dicts and can't quite understand why the list will not populate. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah, try it now. I fixed an error in the solution I suggested earlier.